# RxJs: Executing 3 observables one after another and using results from first in second, and first and second in third requests

Tags: javascript, typescript, dictionary, rxjs, observable

I need to be able to execute 3 observables one after another so that I can use result value from 1st one in second and also 1st and 2nd result in the third one.

Something like this (*it doesn't work as the serviceId is not visible in the third request*):

```
private setupStuff(): void {
        this.initRouteParams().pipe(
            switchMap(serviceId => this.getFileInfo(serviceId)),
            switchMap(fileName => this.getExistingFile(serviceId, fileName)
                .subscribe(response => {
                    console.log(response);
                }))
            );
    }
```

Comment: Where do `serviceId` and `fileName` come from?

Comment: `serviceId` comes from `initRouteParams().pipe` and `fileName` from `this.getFileInfo(serviceId)`

Comment: serviceId is not accessible in the third request because the scope of serviceId is limited to the first switchMap only and also compiler won't find it in lexical scope

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can explicitly return the value of the serviceN to the serviceN+1. Here's the idea :

```
private setupStuff() {
  this.initRouteParams()
    .pipe(
      switchMap(serviceId => {
        return zip(of(serviceId), this.getFileInfo(serviceId))
      }),
      switchMap(([serviceId, filename]) => {
        return zip(of(serviceId), of(filename), this.getExistingFile(serviceId, filename))
      })
    )
    .subscribe(([serviceId, filename, response]) => {
      console.log(serviceId, filename, response);
    })
}
```

Edit:

You can fix types errors by explicitly declare types of each input. You probably want to assign the appropriate type for `response`.

Comment: still this error: ```Error:(93, 27) TS2345: Argument of type '(serviceId) => UnaryFunction<Observable<{}>, Observable<[{}, string, string]>>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: string, index: number) => ObservableInput<{}>'.
  Type 'UnaryFunction<Observable<{}>, Observable<[{}, string, string]>>' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.
  Observable<[{}, string, string]>>'.``` on this line `switchMap((serviceId) => {` and this one `switchMap(([serviceId, filename]) => {`

Comment: I have also tried with that yesterday and it threw the same errors. I’ll try your updated answer, thanks!

Answer (score -2):

managed to solve it like this:

```
private checkFilePresence(): void {
        const first$: Observable<string> = this.initRouteParams();
        const second$: Observable<string> = first$.pipe(
            switchMap(config => {
                return this.getFileInfo(config);
            })
        );
        const third$: Observable<CkitExistingFileResponse> = combineLatest(first$, second$).pipe(
            switchMap(([config, second]) => {
                return this.getExistingFile(config, second);
            })
        );
        combineLatest(first$, third$)
            .subscribe(() => {
            });
    }
```

Comment: first observable will run twice

Comment: I was wrong, it actually runs thrice - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-taltui. Use madjaoue's solution, it's the ideal one shown in tons of examples for this kind problems

Comment: @HikmatG. every observable in this situation runs only once. Just checked again.

Comment: It's just matter of time. In your situation it takes a while for observable to complete, that's why all of other calls wait for that response. But if it would complete a bit faster, you'd see the problems. I just want you know it's not good practice to rely on observable's resolving time

Comment: @HikmatG.can ohhh I see. Can you also suggest your answer?

Comment: As I said before, use madjaoue's answer, but don't just copy paste it, take the logic